# "Window size:x" " Viewport size:x " appearing in print overlay of a webpage in MAC OS Chrome and Safari browsers

Tags: html, css, web

The Web page i am working on has a print option in the web page. But my Client came up with a bug that show the following two lines in print page overlay whenever he clicks on print option.

Window size:x
Viewport size:x

He is testing it on MAC OS chrome browser and MAC OS safari browser(And this is reproducible only in these browsers of MAC OS). As i am working in Windows OS chrome browser and Firefox I am not able to reproduce this issue.
What can be the solution for this issue using only CSS?

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced the same issue in firefox but it worked fine on chrome .

A quick fix is to make the below change in your CSS

```
#window-resizer-tooltip {
    display:none !important;
    }
```

The issue seems to be something to do with your viewport related meta tag .